# Creating navigation system for unity model

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on making a game where a computer navigates around objects to complete tasks. I could use a `NavMeshAgent`; however, I would have to bake all object that would be navigated, slowing the computer down. I am working on making my own navigation system and would like some guidance.

My idea is that when the computer encounters an object, he will find the corners of the object's hitbox from his view, and then decide which corner is closer to the target.

[image: Visual]

The problem I have with this idea is that I don't know exactly how to find the outside edges of a hitbox, so I am looking for a way to do this.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, I'm just looking for a way to make a simple navigation script.

Comment: You have to bake all objects? no you dont

Comment: @Eddge what do you have to do to make the neighbor interact with an avoid obstacles then?

Comment: Make the NavMesh Dynamic?  There are several videos on how to do it

Comment: @Eddge ok thank you I will try that